# Retrieve tweets tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

How can I retrieve only my tweets with a stream? I test that but I don't see my tweets.

**My first attempt:**

```
streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
streamingAPI.userstream(_with='followings')
streamingAPI.filter()
```

**My second attempt:**

```
streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
streamingAPI.filter(follow= ['2466458114'])
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want stream only tweets on your user, you can use the following lines:

```
from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import Stream
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(StreamListener):

   def on_data(self, data):
       print(data)

  def on_error(self, status):
      print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = CustomStreamListener()
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener)
    twitterStream.filter(follow=['2466458114'])
```

In your question, you said that you can't see your tweets. I don't know if is clear or not but just to be sure, with streaming you can see only the "real time" tweets. So also with my code, if you don't tweet nothing, you don't see nothing.

**UPDATE AFTER CHAT IN COMMENTS**

Since Twitter Official API has the bother limitation of time constraints, you can't get older tweets than a week.
For this task I suggest you to use this great [python library](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python).
It allows to get how many tweets you want and wrote when you want. 
As documentation says, you can simply use it in this way:

```
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername('<user_without_@>').setSince("2015-05-01").setUntil("2015-09-30")
```

If you are using python2.X you can use `got`, instead if you are using python3.X you can use `got3`.

I prepare an example in Python3:

```
from getOldTweets import got3
tweetCriteria = got3.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername('barackobama').setSince("2015-09-01").setUntil("2015-09-30")
tweets_list = got3.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
for tweet in tweets_list:
    print(tweet.text)
```

Let me know.

Comment: It's notre all my tweets for exemple have a yesterday tweet?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, would you like your tweets of yesterday?

Comment: All tweets in my account regardless of the date

Comment: I can do this with a stream because I want to use spark streaming?

Comment: I don't think so... because Twitter has the bother limitation of time constraints

Comment: You are welcome. lease if the answer was helpful mark it